# How to call native cordova plugin from javascript function in android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created one java class which extends CordovaPlugin.

For eg,

```
public class SampleCardovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
        callbackContext.success(message);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
```

}

I'm using cordova2.5.0.

How would I call this plugin from my javascript function? 
Please do the needful.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066122/cordova-plugin-javascript-function-call-from-native-in-ios-4-0-0/44819500#44819500

Answer (score 3):

You must first register your plugin in the config.xml in the res folder.

Then in the javascript:

```
cordova.exec(
    function(winParam) {},
    function(error) {},
    "service",
    "action",
    ["firstArgument", "secondArgument", 42, false]);
```

so in your case

```
cordova.exec(
    function(data) { console.log(data);},
    function(error) { console.log(error);},
    "SampleCardovaPlugin",
    "echo",
    ["echo"]);
```

You must also be sure that the device is ready

take a look at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create plugin** (java class, package.json, plugin.xml ...) There is no easier way how to do it. But you can create really simple one (much easier then that one from documentation) -> **[read more here on my blog](https://filipmolcik.com/how-to-call-cordova-android-function-from-javascript/).**

Then you call it in JS like this:

```
cordova.exec(function(success) {},          //success callback
         function(error) {},                //error callback
         "Example",                         //class name
         "YOUR_ACTION_NAME_PARAMETER",      //action name 
         ["Dog", "Pig", 42, false]);        //args
```