# Cordova Plugin Javascript Function call from Native in iOS 4.0.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am trying to call javascript function from native plugin in cordova iOS 4.0.0.
In the previous cordova ios version 3.9.2, I can call any javascript function from native plugin like this.

```
- (void)PlayMp3:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{       

    NSString* callbackId = [command callbackId];
    NSString* name = [[command arguments] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hello, %@", name];

    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult
                               resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                               messageAsString:msg];

    MainViewController* viewController = (MainViewController*)self.viewController;

    NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setPlayStatus();"];
    [viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

    [self success:result callbackId:callbackId];
}
```

But in Cordova iOS 4.0.0, I can't call javascript function `setPlayStatus()` like as above. Because `viewController.webview` is not `UIWebView` type. It is `UIView`. So I was tried to like this.

```
- (void)PlayMp3:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    WKWebView* webview = (WKWebView*)self.viewController.view;

    NSString *jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setPlayStatus();"];
   [webview evaluateJavaScript:@"setPlayStatus();" completionHandler:nil];

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}
```

But it didn't work. How can I call javascript function in native cordova plugin in Cordova Plugin iOS 4.0.0?

Comment: What error are you getting? Is it that the object doesn't respond to the selector `evaluateJavaScript `?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everybody. I have done it.`CDVPlugin` has a `commandDelegate`. This `commandDelegate` can call `javascript` function with `evalJS` function.
So I tried like this.

```
[self.commandDelegate evalJS:@"setPlayStatus()"];
```

After that the `setPlayStatus()` function was called.

Answer (score 1):

I just quickly read the Cordova iOS plugin code and it looks like `self.viewController.webView` is holding a UIWebView via the webEngine.  It might be able to be either.

You should use `isKindOfClass:` to check before casting.

EDIT: Even better: the engine is a protocol that has this:

```
- (void)evaluateJavaScript:(NSString*)javaScriptString completionHandler:(void (^)(id, NSError*))completionHandler;
```

Use:

```
[self.viewController.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:@"setPlayStatus();" completionHandler:nil]
```

Answer (score 1):

A typo in @Tim Rogers's answer, it should be evalJs instead of evalJS:

`[self.commandDelegate evalJs:@"setPlayStatus()"];`

it works fine with Cordova ios 4.1.1

Sorry I don't have 50 reputations to add a comment so have to add a new answer here

Answer (score 0):

I've tried myself and this works for me

```
[self.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"funcName(%@)",yourparam]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same Issue where I tried below code to make .js call from native, and again I am using Cordova.exec to send parameters

```
[self.webViewEngine evaluateJavaScript:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setPlayStatus()"];
```

below feature you have to add in config.xml

```
<feature name="setPlayStatus">
        <param name="ios-package" value="setPlayStatus" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
   </feature>
```

This works for me.